# react queue with state and handling

Tags: reactjs, queue

I need to implement a system of elevators using React and one of the requirements is to use a queue for the calls of the elevator.
The queue holds members which are the numbers of the floors that the elevators have to go to next.
When you put a floor number in the queue, I need another function, which probably uses useEffect, which handles the request and sends an elevator to the desired floor.

I ran into a problem when trying to iterate over the requests in a queue.

What I'm missing? How can I make it work and better? Thank you!

I tried using something like this-

```
const [requestQueue, setRequestQueue] = React.useState([]);
React.useEffect(() => {
  setRequestQueue(([request, ...rest]) =>
    //handle the request
    return rest
})
}, [requestQueue])
```

but I get React error for doing that and it loops forever.